# Spritekit constraint zRotation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, rotation, skaction

I have a node with SKAction infinite repeat a zRotation, and i need to rotate another node with the exact same zRotation at the same time. (I can't put those nodes in a same node container)
I would like to use an SKConstraint but this kind of constraint do not exist
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in SKScene that you can override called `didEvaluateActions`  This is the moment in the update cycle that all actions have performed their tasks (but not necessarily completed).

Set the 2nd node's `zRotation` to the first nodes during this moment.